# Responsive CSS issues on different iOS devices

Tags: html, css, responsive, w3.css

I have a couple of issues with my CSS, I am currently using W3.CSS library to build a basic responsive website, I have media queries for small devices and for some reason it works on my phone but not on my computer when I resize to the small size, it used to work on the old version of the site but not anymore.

The second issue is very recent, in fact it's today; For some reason the website does not work on a different 'iPhone'.. My explanation is probably because it is a different iOS version? as that 'iPhone' is iOS10.3 and my phone is on iOS10.1.1

In conclusion, I just would like to add, should I change the library to Bootstrap or is W3.CSS good enough? Sorry if I come out as a bit naive but I am new to responsive design.

Homepage code example:

```
.main-div{   //main div is supposed to be the main content box
  max-width: 75%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-div{ //sidebar div is supposed to be the sidebar content box
  max-width: 24%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* responsive css */

  /* mobile portrait&landscape */

  @media screen and(max-width: 768px){
    .main-div, .sidebar-div{
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post code example?

Comment: Hey @Le Khoa Nhi I have updated the code!